# Test postgresql connection string using psql at bash command line?

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, psql

If I have a postgresql connection string:

```
export my_conn='postgresql://vadmin:Gimme5br@platform-prod.clfk51eo.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/prod'
```

how can I test this connection? I tried:

```
pqsl "$my_conn"
```

and it just hangs

Comment: I'm going to assume that the typo above (`pqsl` vs `psql`) is just a typo in creating the question. If the above is hanging, I'd expect that your issue is some kind of connection issue between your server and the database you are connecting to. Maybe a firewall or routing issue, but also maybe a shell expansion issue. You might want to try to reformulate the connection directly from the command line using `psql -U vadmin -h platform-prod.clfk51eo.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -d prod` to see if you are able to connect that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best tool for the purpose is [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html).

Simply run

```
pg_isready -d "$my_conn"
```

and check the return code.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to open up a shell, something like `psql>`

Comment: not entirely, if you can open a shell, you can connect

Comment: I thought you wanted to test the connection. Why would you want an interactive shell for that?

Answer (score 13):

Run this instead:

```
psql "$my_conn" -c "SELECT 1"
```

This would try to execute a simple query that always should return a one-row result and then exit.
Also you could check the exit code of the operation by calling:

```
echo $?
```

Anything different than `0` would mean some error.